# Jquery .Show() function on certains options in a select tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have 3 select inputs that depends on the selected value of the other (similar to state/city/postal code).

Here is mi code: https://jsfiddle.net/9t74s3fo/

In that specific code, it doesn't work when trying to load the values of "distrito" select when selecting "lima" value in "departamento" select but it works fine when I select a value before "lima". I'm using jQuery to show the values depending on parent selected value.

I realized that happens when there's more than one thousend values in "distrito" select.

Thanks in advance.

```
function handleCombosThatDependOnFields() {
    $("[data-depends-on-field]").each(function () {
        parentFieldId = $(this).attr("data-depends-on-field");
        if (parentFieldId != "") {
            $("#Field_" + parentFieldId).attr("onchange", "changeDependingField(" + parentFieldId + ")");
            changeDependingField(parentFieldId);
        }
    });
}

function changeDependingField(parentFieldId) {
    var parentValue = $("#Field_" + parentFieldId).val();
    var childElem = $("[data-depends-on-field='" + parentFieldId + "']");
    childElem.find("option").hide();
    childElem.find("option[value^='" + parentValue + "|']").show();
}

handleCombosThatDependOnFields()
```

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` cross browser to start with. Some browsers do not support it. Choices are remove/replace or enable/disable

Comment: Also please scale down your demo to just enough elements to display your problem. We don't need to see hundreds of `<option>` to help you resolve the issue. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I see. Thanks @charlietfl I will have to draw in the child select with the options it requires
$("select#ChildSelect").html("<option>a</option><option>b</option>")